# put data in my database php my admin

Tags: phpmyadmin

i put this values into my data base but when open my phpmy admin and go to my table no valuse addet to my database where is my data?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>register
</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('babak');
?>

thanx for your registering &nbsp;<?php
echo $_POST["name"];
?><br />    
your email is <?php echo $_POST["E-MAIL"];
?><br />
<?php
$sql="INSERT INTO users(id,pass) VALUES ($_POST[id],$_POST[pass])"; 


?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just wondering: do you have any actual mysql query being sent? i.e. mysql_query($sql)

Comment: yeah i sent it from a form that i designed before that pages taht action is register.php in form

Comment: But there's nothing actually using the $sql in your above code. You've got a variable, $sql, that doesn't do anything after you've put a value into it. You need to actually make $sql do something - so the next line should be mysql_query($sql);

Comment: i did it what u say but in phpmyadmin no data shows.where i can see my data in php my admin ?????

Comment: You should just be able to check the data in phpmyadmin by going onto the database and then checking the table you wanted to populate (i.e. go into users)

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the sql statment.

```
   mysql_execute($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a connection variable that has to be passed as an argument to
'select_database_db' command

```
//Connect to the server.
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');

//Select our database.
mysql_select_db('babak', $connection);
```